# What are the prophecies about messiah?

Tags: messiah, prophecies

This question may be of a broad nature, but I just want to know that what are are prophecies for the messiah?

Since  [Christianity claims that Jesus fulfilled 44 prophecies](http://christianity.about.com/od/biblefactsandlists/a/Prophecies-Jesus.htm), I am interested to know what are the predictions?

There may be many from Rabbis, but I am interested in the ones from Tanakh.

Comment: There are many prophecies about the Messiah, but most passages aren't absolutely clear. The most oft-discussed passage in this context is 'הנה ישכיל עבדי' in Isiah 42-43. See this question for more info and links: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8857/why-dont-jews-think-jesus-is-the-messiah

Comment: http://www.jewfaq.org/mashiach.htm

Comment: Many related questions: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2044/472

Comment: not just 44 they claim a lot prophecies http://christianthinktank.com/falsechrist.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the assumption that this post is different because it asks specifically what are the Messianic prophecies, and may therefore survive the challenge that it is repetitive of other questions, I will answer.

There are eligibility rules for the Messiah based on various verseus.  These are:

- He must be Jewish -- Deut. 17:15 prohibits us setting a non-Jew as a king over us.  See also Gen. 49:10 ("The scepter shall not depart from Judah....").
- He must be descended from David and Solomon -- I Chron. 17:11-12, 22:9-10; Ps. 89:29-38; Jer. 33.17; 2 Sam. 7:12-16.
- That line will be through the father since the Torah teaches that families registered their ancestry by their "fathers' household." Num. 1:18.
- Rambam (Maimonedes) adds that the Messiah will resolve the numerous rabbinic disputes on Jewish law that came up over the past 2000 years or so after the Roman exile.  Mishna Torah, Hilchos Melachim 11:4.

But more important is the fact that the Messiah must bring about the Messianic Era which would include:

1. World-wide belief in the G-d of Abraham -- Isa. 11:9, 40:5; Zeph. 3:9.
2. World-wide peace -- Isa. 2:4, 11:6; Micah 4:3.
3. Relocation of all Jews to Israel, gathered from the four corners of the earth -- Deut. 30:3-4; Isa. 11:12, 27:12-13.
4. The Temple will be rebuilt -- Micah 4:1.  And
5. Resurrection of the Dead (and resettlement into Israel) -- Isa. 26:19.

Rambam points out that some of these events, and other events must happen within the Messiah's lifetime.  According to Rambam the Messiah in his lifetime must a) cause all Jews to become observant; b) repair issues that divide us on halachic questions; c) fight the wars of Israel, d) rebuild the Temple, and e) gather in the exiles.  Hilchos Melachim 11:4.  If the Messiah fulfilled some miracles but not all, before dying, we cannot regard him to be the Messiah, and instead view him as a test or our own will.  Hilchos Melachim 11:5 (ואם לא  הצליח עד כה או נהרג, בידוע שאינו זה שהבטיחה עליו תודה 
… ולא העמידו הקדוש
ברוך הוא אלא לנסות בו רבים) ("But if he did not succeed in all
this or was killed, he is
definitely not the Moshiach
promised in the Torah... and
G-d only appointed him in
order to test the masses....")
There are certainly other attributes and signs that might indicate that one is or is not the Messiah, but without bringing about the Messianic Age, it doesn't matter if he performed miracles, rode a Donkey into the Old City, or suffered in any kind of manner for any length of time.  The righteous among us produce miracles daily, and many of them suffer daily for the sins of other Jews who deserve puninshment in this world for certain sins, but who might lose faith if he was punished as he deserved.  See Talmud Bavli, Brachos 5a. And, lets be honest, for the right fee, anyone can ride a donkey into the Old City.  The bottom line we expect from the Messiah is that he deliver the Messianic Era; anything less won't work.