# Is a conversion through "Jerusalem Council" valid?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, christianity, messianism

Before I continue, the "Jerusalem Council" is a Messianic Orthodox Jewish movement which basically follows the Talmud and Kaballah and don't believe that Jesus (or Yeshua as they say) is G-d.
Neverthless they believe he is the messiah and they believe that the New Testament is from HaShem. Other than that they seem completely Orthodox Jews.

and here is the link about their views toward Jesus:

http://jerusalemcouncil.org/articles/faqs/is-yeshua-god/

Is a convert to Judaism through this movement is considered valid (according to True Orthodox Jewish Halakha) since they are not technically Christians (other than the belief that Jesus is the Jewish Messiah)?

Comment: Sorry your description and the link that you give seems to imply that they are not valid. If they were valid they would include a certificate from the rabbanut of the state of Israel. The fact that they accept the so-called "New Testament" as valid seems to say that they are really a christian missionary organization no matter what they claim.

Comment: orthoWhat? newWhat? It is perhaps a conversion to christianism. You ask if a Jew that convert to J.C. is a good christian? Perhaps it is better to ask a christian website.

Comment: @mil It's not offensive or that unclear. It's just seems pretty silly. It seems pretty obvious no Orthodox Jew is going to trust these guys with anything. Why are you even asking? This is a Non Useful thread.

Comment: @DoubleAA I assumed the answer would be obvious. But I was curious and saw that what harm can occure from Yeshua believers whose beliefs are completely Jewish except that they belief in a certain man as a non divine Messiah.

Comment: @mil In all likelihood there beliefs are not completely Jewish and they are not well trained in implementing Halakha properly. Like 99% likelihood.

Comment: I think that if one were to look at the quotes on the linked page one would not trust their scholarship and understanding of Judaism, and therefore, their claim to anything else.

Comment: Hmmm not sure, I personally don't see anything wrong with them (I'm not Messianic.)

Answer (score 4):

They are not Orthodox if they believe that the messiah has already come.  More specifically, a claim that Jesus was the messiah is counter to Judaism.  You can learn more about the requirements of the messiah [in this answer to a related question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/25581/472).

Because they are not Orthodox, their "conversions" will not be accepted by Orthodox authorities.  But, more broadly, because they are not *Jewish*, their "conversions" will not be accepted by anybody in the Jewish community.  Christians cannot make Jewish converts any more than the US can make Canadian citizens.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Great answer but just curious, would you not consider Lubavitch Meshichistim to be "Orthodox"?  (I don't think they do conversions, so that aspect is moot...)

Comment: @SAH I don't know enough about the complexities of Lubavich to have an opinion on that.  I have the impression that there are some differences within their community on this point.  Also, I've also heard they don't do conversions.