# Which prophecy in specific did Jesus not fulfill?

Tags: christianity, nevua-prophecy

Which particular prophecy or prophecies do Jews believe Jesus did not fulfill?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/25581/3

Comment: The first answer posted pretty much sums up the feelings of every Jewish person who is familiar with Messianic Prophecies in scripture. There are many other prophecies/ideas that Jesus did not fulfill, but they aren't really easy to get into as many of them involve mistranslations or misinterpretations. For example, there is no Virgin Birth prophecy in the Hebrew Bible. This "prophecy" only exists because the Greek translation of the Hebrew Bible mistranslated "young woman" to "virgin." So even some "prophecies" that were  supposedly"fulfilled" weren't actual prophecies to begin with.

Comment: @mevaqesh Your phone is worse to you than mine is to me! My comment was auto-generated when I voted to close, inspired by WAF's comment. I've deleted it now.

Comment: For a christian perspective, if interested, check Chapter 4 of [this book](http://www.salvationisfromthejews.com/index.shtml)

Answer (score 2):

I think this has probably been answered but I will put the information here just in case it hasn't.

> Jesus Did Not Fulfill the Messianic Prophecies
>
> What is the Messiah supposed to accomplish?
>
> One of the central themes of biblical prophecy is the promise of a future age of perfection characterized by universal peace and recognition of God. (Isaiah 2:1-4, 32:15-18, 60:15-18; Zephaniah 3:9; Hosea 2:20-22; Amos 9:13-15; Micah 4:1-4; Zechariah 8:23, 14:9; Jeremiah 31:33-34)
>   Specifically, the Bible says he will:
>
> Build the Third Temple (Ezekiel 37:26-28).
>
> Gather all Jews back to the Land of Israel (Isaiah 43:5-6).
>
> Usher in an era of world peace, and end all hatred, oppression, suffering and disease. As it says: "Nation shall not lift up sword against nation, neither shall man learn war anymore." (Isaiah 2:4)
>
> Spread universal knowledge of the God of Israel, which will unite humanity as one. As it says: "God will be King over all the world – on that day, God will be One and His Name will be One" (Zechariah 14:9).
>
> If an individual fails to fulfill even one of these conditions, then he cannot be the Messiah.

From [here](http://www.aish.com/jw/s/48892792.html).

Comment: @Jesse You aren't really in a place to judge what is or isn't taken out of context.  One of the examples you provided as being "fulfilled" by Jesus is Isaiah 7:14, but you (and nearly all Christians) do not translate the verse correctly. There is no virgin birth in the Hebrew Bible, and thankfully, we now live in  time where Christian Scholars will even admit there is no virgin birth. Here is information regarding the mistranslation of Isaiah 7:14 http://bibleodyssey.org/en/people/related-articles/was-there-really-a-virgin-birth-in-the-bible.aspx

Comment: @Jesse the messiah position comes with job requirements.  Jesus didn't satisfy the requirements, thus was not the messiah.  If somebody in the future satisfies those requirements then that person will be the messiah.  Claims in advance of proof don't mean anything. Christian evangelism is not welcome here, so I am deleting your comment (which is also incorrect, as Aaron pointed out).