# Did Zechariah predict the coming of Jesus

Tags: messiah, christianity, messianism, zecharia-book-of

Did Zechariah predict the coming of Jesus?

One will say to him, 'What are these wounds between your hands?' Then he will answer, 'Those with which I was wounded in the house of my friends. Zechariah 13:6

https://youtu.be/KpNHxwkd38Y

Comment: Do you have any reason to think that this is a reference to Jesus in particular as opposed to anyone else who ever lived or will live with a hand wound? The onus of proof is one someone claiming it _does_ refer to him. There may or may not be a disproof that it refers to him, just as there may or many not be disproof that it refers to billions of other people.

Comment: Related, possible dupe: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8857/why-dont-jews-think-jesus-is-the-messiah.

Comment: What sort of evidence are you looking for? Are you asking whether this is the traditional Jewish understanding? I assume you know it is not.

Comment: @Sean Kelly R' Singer's video is simply saying that were Zechariah talking about Jesus, it would be a bad thing for Bible believing Christians. But he obviously says that we don't know who it is. If there is more detail to your question, please edit and tell us.

Comment: @mevaqesh That question is related, but I'm not sure why you think this is a duplicate. (To other close voters: I don't either think this is comparative religion. This question does not "[require] of its answerers any knowledge of a religion besides Judaism.")

Comment: @Shokhet i am not sure it is a dupe, which is why I didn't VTC. However, as I noted, there are billions of possible people the verse could be referring to, and it would be quite difficult to disprove that it refer to any of them. The only reason to think it might be Jesus is if one thinks he were a predicted prophet. If that is what the question is trying to ask, it comes close to being a dupe.

Comment: @mevaqesh "Proof" in this context usually refers to commentaries; if some *parshan* or other linked Jesus to this verse (or posited that the verse refers to some *other* individual or class), then we would have an answer to the question. || Even if the basis of this question is "Jesus is a predicted prophet," it's still not a dupe. The other question is "why don't Jews believe in the prophecies of Jesus?;" this question is "Is Jesus mentioned in this verse?" -- not even close to duplication, IMO.

Comment: no, he did no such thing

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to to with the hands in the sense that they pretend was due to the Romans. In fact, Rashi says that the context is speaking about **false** prophets (verse 2). If it were talking about Jesus it would be calling him a false prophet. As we see in Rashi on 13:2

> **And also the prophets:** The false prophets.

[Zechariah 13:6](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16217#v=6&showrashi=true)

> And one will say to him, "What are these wounds between your hands?"
>   And he shall say, "That I was smitten in the house of my friends."

**Rashi**

> **And one will say to him, “What are these wounds between your hands?”:**
>   Between your shoulders. There they flog the sinners.
>
> **in the house of my friends:** who loved me and reproved me to the
>   straight path.

In the context of your question, Zechariah is speaking of what will happen **after** the mashiach comes and the House of David restored. In that time, the false prophets will be ashamed of what they have done and the lies that they have told. They will deny have prophesied at all (much less falsely) and say that the marks of punishment are not punishment for having prophesied falsely, but for other sins.

Thus, even though *oso haish* was a false prophet (according to his followers), he is still not referenced here as that time still had many false prophets who refused to admit their errors.