# Seforim on Moshiach

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, messiah

I was hoping someone could give me the names of several Seforim which are best with regard to Inyanei Moshiach?

I refer specifically to Moshiach as in the person himself, not the time period. In other words, a Sefer which identifies various Remazim, the various names and titles associated, and so forth.

For example, among the more well-known names are Menachem, Yinun, Tzemach, etc. and titles Go'el, Moshiah, Ben-Dovid, Uri (or Oori), etc. There are many, many more, and that's one of the items I'm looking for, along with several others.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodea Zeke!

Answer (score 7):

There is an interesting series of two volumes -as of now- titled '[Yemot HaMashiach BeHalachah](http://www.shturem.net/index.php?section=news&id=212)' by R. AYB Gerlitski. He did a great comprehensive work, encyclopedic style, on all different relevant subjects regarding Moshiach and the epoch of his arrival.

[image: title page]

Answer (score 3):

You can start with the final chapter in the Rambam - Hilchos Melachim U’milchamoseihem 12. He intersperses throughout the chapter aspects about Mashiach himself (how we will know who he is) and aspects about the time period after his arrival and the redemption. Do note that there is no one sugya in Shas that discusses this; while there’s a lot addressed at the beginning of Chelek, the Rambam’s sources are all over the place.

Answer (score 2):

There is an interesting book by R Gil Student called [*Can The Rebbe Be Moshiach*](http://moshiachtalk.tripod.com/)?

In the course of the book, he describes various characteristics of Moshiach himself.

The book can be read online [here](http://moshiachtalk.tripod.com/) or purchased [here](http://a.co/fStnHFX) (amazon).

Comment: Eh, any book that disproves Jesus as the Moshiach would work too.

Comment: @ezra of course, especially if this book was by a learned rabbi, had good sources, described the real Moschiach and was easily available online :->

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: @Laser123 How does an answer citing a book that describes the characteristics of Mashiach himself not answer the question asking for a source that describes the characteristics of Mashiach himself?

Comment: @ezra If that's all the OP wants, try [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8857/why-dont-jews-think-jesus-is-the-messiah) right here on MY. I don't think that sufficiently answers this question.

Answer (score 1):

[*The Future: Guide to Messiah*](http://www.feldheim.com/the-future-guide-to-messiah.html)

[*Rubashkin, the Redemption and Yearning for Moshiach*](https://www.sefaria.org/sheets/70397)

[*The Seven Fold Mission of the Messiah and How We Know We Found the Right Person*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WCDLMXOVKyc)

Answer (score 0):

[Eim Habanim Semeicha](http://mysefer.com/Hebrew/Jewish-Philosophy--Thought/Eim-Habanim-Smeicha-__p-73-174-1256.aspx) by Rav yissachar shlomo teichtal zt"l

[*Netzach Yisrael*](https://www.sefaria.org/texts/Philosophy/Maharal?lang=bi) by the Maharal zt"l

[Yeshuot Meshicho and Miflaot Elokim](http://mysefer.com/Hebrew/Jewish-Philosophy--Thought/Mifalot-Elokim--Yeshuot-Meshicho---Rabbi-Don-Yitzchak-Abarbanel__p-73-174-3152.aspx) by the abarbanel zt"l

[Sefer HaGeulah](http://mysefer.com/Hebrew/Jewish-Philosophy--Thought/Shaar-HaGemul-LRamban-Peirush-Chazon-Yoel__p-73-174-448.aspx) of the Ramban zt"l

[*Otzrot Acharit HaYamim*](http://bit.ly/2nM19w7) by Yehuda Hayoun

Comment: Is Eim Habanim Semeicha really about Moshiach? Which part?

Comment: the entie sefer

Comment: Hmmm. That is not my recollection from learning it - at least not in relation to the question here - but maybe I forgot since then

Comment: @mbloch, Seems that the first perek is concerning moshiach. See online here: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=53692&st=&pgnum=7&hilite=)

Comment: Not sure also if that answers the question here, though.