# Is Messianic Judaism accepted as a branch of Judaism by any other branch?

Tags: messianism

My question on Messianic Judaism was closed on this site, stating that it is not Judaism. Is this the common position of all branches except Messianic Jews themselves?

Comment: @Harel13 Please do not become angry on me. I am just a Muslim who is curious to Judaism but doesn't know

Comment: I'm not angry. I simply left that comment on the other question so you'd know why it was off-topic for the site.

Comment: ok that's fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is the generally accepted position of all branches.

[Here](https://jewsforjesus.org/publications/issues/issues-v12-n05/why-arent-messianic-jews-accepted-by-the-jewish-community) is an article, written by a member of the Jews for Jesus movement itself, pointing out how Jews reject Jesus across the board. The article specifically mentions how even the Reform and Conservative Jews reject messianic judaism as being a legitimate form of Judaism. Likewise, the Israeli Supreme Court ruled that the "Right of Return" which allows all Jews to automatically be eligible for making aliyah, doesn't apply to messianic jews.
While the article is ultimately trying to argue that Jews should accept messianic judaism as legitimate, it clearly shows how the movement is not currently accepted by any major branch of judaism.

For more information about why Jews don't view jesus as the messiah, see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8857/21984).