# What are some hard proofs Jesus was not the messiah?

Tags: messiah

I’ve heard that him being descended from Jeconiah disqualifies him but I saw a analysis that he in fact descended from a different jeconiah.

The Tanakh also doesn’t rule out a second coming to fulfill all the prophecies.

I’ve heard from rabbi tovia singer that the messiah must come after the second temple destruction but I may have misunderstood him.

Comment: Check here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8857/why-dont-jews-think-jesus-is-the-messiah?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C64.2733

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Bernard and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: I believe you did misunderstand Rabbi Singer. He has many videos on the topic though, all available through YouTube. Here is just one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YGI88qej8SI      Remember, the burden of proof is on the claimant, not on the world. Or else it's your job to prove I'm not the Messiah.